# Don't Switch to Speakers When Bluetooth Goes Out of Range

Tags: macos, bluetooth, headphones

So here I am at work, rocking out to Pandora, when I decide "Hey! I could really use some water".  So I carelessly put my cheap-o Bluetooth headphones around my neck and head off to the water fountain.

30 seconds later my co-workers get blasted by Arctic Monkeys.

**Is there any way to keep audio from switching to speakers when (for any reason) my Bluetooth connection fails?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a (mostly) satisfactory answer!

1. Plug in a pair of normal headphones - the audio will switch to them.
2. Open "Sound Preferences..."

[image: open preferences]

3. Switch back to your Bluetooth device

.
[image: Sound preferences]

Your sound will now fall-back to the wired headphones.  There may still be a bit of noise, but your office-neighbors will enjoy the reduction.

Comment: Bonus!  Snip the plug off of an old pair of headphones and plug that in.  No sound-overflow.